# Daily scheduled notifications

Tags: notifications, swift3

I need a bit of guidance, so for my application i'm looking at using local notifications to send a notification every morning at 7 o'clock.

The issue i'm having is how can i make the content for the local notification dynamic mainly the body and the attached image? As it will vary for the user on a daily basis.

What would be the best way to go about this since you can't edit future notifications.

Comment: @matt removed the word push, im talking about notifications which are scheduled locally on the application, not sure why it warrant a down vote because of a wording mistake....

Comment: Let's talk about what you're trying to do. Are you saying the notification text will vary but you cannot configure the notification in advance? When _can_ you configure it?

Comment: @matt yes the text and the image in the notification will vary for different days. Since i will be displaying the weather the daily forecast will be different on different days

Comment: Then you can't do it with local notifications. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a little lesson about notifications. First, what is a notification? It's basically an alert presented on your behalf *by the system*. Second, there are two kinds of notification: local and remote.

Let's imagine, then, an app that aims to present a notification to the user every morning at 7 AM saying what the current temperature is outside. (Assume for purposes of the example that we have a way of learning this information.)

A moment's thought will reveal that this cannot be done with *local* notifications. We cannot know the current temperature at 7 AM until 7 AM (or close to it) and we cannot schedule the notification unless the app is running. Therefore we would need the great good luck to have the app running at 6:59 AM in order for this app to work. But an app only runs when the user summons it, so that is extremely unlikely.

Therefore a task of this kind is possible only with *remote* notifications. A remote server is always running; therefore it can get the temperature and "ping" the user's device at 7 AM, and the system will present the notification on your behalf. You would therefore need to possess such a server in order to write the imagined app.

(An alternative using local notifications would be this: You schedule, say, a week's worth of local notification in advance. Then if you have the great good luck to find the app running before a notification is presented, you tear down all the scheduled notifications and do it again with a more up-to-date forecast. But of course this cannot possibly work as well as using remote notifications, and it will stop working entirely after a week if the user doesn't launch the app. That, to put it bluntly, sounds pretty lame.)