# Swift: how to schedule local notifications with dynamic content

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I have a weather app for iOS, and I'd like to allow the user to receive a notification each morning at a time of their choosing which would fetch the weather forecast for the day and display a notification.

I'd like to avoid using push notifications, and I thought I might be able to use local notifications, except I can't see a way to fetch the content to be shown from a server. It looks like the content has to be set at the time of scheduling. Is that right?

That makes me think I might be able to register my application to use background execution to periodically fetch the weather and schedule a notification with the latest content, but this seems wasteful.

In short, I'd like to tell iOS to run a specific function at a specific time. Is there a good option for this that I'm missing? Are push notifications the only/best way to accomplish this sort of thing?

Comment: you can schedule local notification with your content.

Comment: @KKRocks perhaps I wasn't clear enough with my question. The problem I see is that I'd like to fetch the content to be shown in the local notification at the time I'm showing the notification. So, in my case, the user might schedule a 7am notification, and I'd like to fetch the content for the notification at that time.

Comment: yes then push notification is best option for your if you want to display weather  forecast .

Comment: @Truth Potatoe given my requirements, are push notifications the recommended solution?

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41901767/3901620

Comment: Yes, that's helpful, thank you. It sounds like push notifications are really the only viable option for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push notification is best option for your if you want to display `weather forecast` .

More about this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41901767/3901620

Answer (score 2):

You can schedule a local notification for a specific time and when a user sees it and if he wants he can open your app by tapping on that notification. At that time, you will able to know that, a user has tapped on a notification and thus the app is open, you can make a network call to fetch the data and show it inside the application. **This will not require any background calls therefor and only make a network call to an action by a user.**

Another option: You can create a widget of your app (like Weather Widget). Whenever a user goes into widget area you will get a delegate call and make a network call to get the latest weather data. If a user wants more information on it, he can simply tap on it and your app will open. Then, everything will be in your hands.

Your option: You can always get dynamic content whenever the user opens your app for a particular date and set a notification for it. But this is not suggestible as the user may not get updated data.

Push Notification: This may not be required with your case, however, if you want to send the dynamic data over your server to your app. This is always the best option.

Answer (score 0):

i have created a function. In which this will call your function at a specific time, when you want. Am creating a clock app so i need to trigger a local notification when ever user created the alarm. And in the notification Center Delegate method, you can handle your response and call the whatever method you want.

```
class LocalNotificationMethod : NSObject {

static let notificationInstance = LocalNotificationMethod()

let requestIdentifier = "SampleRequest" //identifier is to cancel the notification request

 internal func scheduleLocalNotification(titleOfNotification:String, subtitleOfNotification:String, messageOfNotification:String, soundOfNotification:String, dateOfNotification:String) {

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"
        let date3 = formatter.date(from: dateOfNotification)

        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.body = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: titleOfNotification, arguments: nil)
        content.sound = soundOfNotification.characters.count > 0 ? UNNotificationSound.init(named: soundOfNotification + ".mp3") : UNNotificationSound.default()

        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger.init(dateMatching: NSCalendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year, .hour, .minute], from: date3!), repeats: false)

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier:requestIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request){(error) in

            if (error != nil){

                print(error?.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                print("Successfully Done")
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }

}
}
```

And in AppDelegate Methods : - You can handle whenever user click on your notification or whenever your notification will be present.Is up to you what you want to done.

//MARK:- Notification Delegates

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    print("Tapped in notification")
}

//This is key callback to present notification while the app is in foreground
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {


    print("Notification being triggered")
    //You can either present alert ,sound or increase badge while the app is in foreground too with ios 10
    //to distinguish between notifications
    if notification.request.identifier == "SampleRequest" {

        completionHandler( [.alert,.sound,.badge])

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not seeing how this does what I needed. What I'm looking to do is (a) schedule a notification to be sent daily at 7am, and (b) to be able to fetch the text for the notification from my server at 7am. In the `willPresent` function, are you able to fetch json etc from a server?