# Local notifications repeat interval using calendar triggers

Tags: swift, uilocalnotification, usernotifications

I'm setting up some local notifications as reminders.
So far I've been able to set a non repeating notification which triggers from a date picked from a datePicker.

```
let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
    dateformatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.medium
    dateformatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
    let dateFromString = dateformatter.date(from: selectDateTextField.text!)
    let fireDateOfNotification: Date = dateFromString!

    //if permission allowed
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = notifTitleTextField.text!
    content.body = notifNoteTextView.text
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    let triggerDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year,.month,.day,.hour,.minute,.second,], from: fireDateOfNotification)
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDate,
                                                repeats: false)
    //Schedule the Notification
    let titleNospace = notifTitleTextField.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
    let identifier = titleNospace
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier!, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    self.center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    })
```

Now i would like the user to pick from a list (or a Picker) the repeating interval (hourly, daily, weekly, monthly, yearly or every x days).
Is there a simple way to do so or i need to create a custom class?
is it correct to make it through a series of if else statement? (it seems to me a bit off, doesn't really seems to be the correct way)
Thanks.

Comment: I recommend you reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41901767/3687801) before you're trying to implement such a thing!!

Comment: @nayem thx but i don't need push notification... what i'm trying to do is simply to let user set a reminder (e.g clean the swimming pool filter) and set a repeating interval (e.g each month). Local notification are good fit for this. all the infos are set by the user

Answer (score 2):

If you set up a `UNCalendarNotificatonTrigger`, you cannot manipulate its repetition interval when you set `repeats = true`, since it will be repeating at each date when the date components of the trigger are matched. To give you an example, if you only set up the `hour, minute and second` components, your notification will be repeated daily, since the exact hour, minute and second values occur each day. If you only set up `minute and second`, the notification will repeat every hour.

What you are looking for is the `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger`, this is the one using which you can set up the repetition interval.

However, to match your criteria, you need to mix both triggers. You should first set up a non-repeating `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` and once that notification is delivered, set up a repeating `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` with the time interval coming from the user. See [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/untimeintervalnotificationtrigger)

Comment: thank for the answer. So basically i should use this UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications(completionHandler: {deliveredNotifications -> () in and in here set the UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger?but how can i the specific identifier if i don't set it once i schedule the notification but after is delivered?

Comment: Yes, if you want to access the notifications not opened by the user, use that method. You can store arbitrary data in `UNNotificationContent`'s `userInfo` property, so you can store the time interval there and then check this value in `getDeliveredNotifications` for each delivered notification. Of just store the identifier of the scheduled notifications in a dictionary along with the time intervals corresponding to each notification.

Comment: ok... but you said notification not opened... what if the user tapped on the notification, will not be repeated anymore? sorry but i'm totally new to this...

Comment: `getDeliveredNotifications` only returns the notifications that are still in the `Notification Center`, meaning that the user have not opened them yet. Since your first notification set up with the `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` will not be repeating, it will be removed from `Notification Center` as soon as user opens it. For this reason, you should schedule the notification with the `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` as soon as the user receives the first notification at the specified date.

Comment: For more information, see the [Local and Remote notification Programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH5-SW1) and especially the *Responding to the Delivery of Notifications* part.

Comment: No worries. If you found my answer helpful, please consider accepting it.

Comment: sure... i'l try and then get back.. :)

Comment: I don't believe this would work as you cannot execute any code on notification delivery if the app is not active. Correct me if I am wrong...